# Does hard disk spin when PC sleeps?

Tags: hard-drive, sleep

When I put a Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 8.1 PC on sleep mode, does the spinning of hard disk turn off or is kept on? I am talking about the internals of the hard disk and general sleep mode not hibernate.

Comment: I'm pretty sure on earlier versions of Windows (eg, maybe W95) you could control whether the drive spins down on sleep, but I don't see the option on Vista.

Answer (score 6):

For both S3 (Sleep, or Standby) and S4 (hibernate) sleep modes, the hard disk is turned off, along with anything else that isn't needed.

For S3 sleep mode, this can be every subsystem aside from RAM.  There is sufficient information in RAM to restore the computer to its awake state.

For S4 sleep mode, this can be every subsystem, including RAM, as this is written to disk - the PC is then powered off.

In reality, some parts of the system are left active in a lower power state, such as network cards and input devices, as these are sometimes used to bring the PC back from sleep.

However, the hard disk is not one of the systems that are left running.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they should power down (as pretty much any component not required to wake up again or keep the PCs current state).

For hybernation, the RAM contents are written to the disk and loaded again when waking up, which is skipped in sleep (RAM is just kept active to not lose contents).

However, you can forbid Windows to turn off hard disks to save power, which I think should keep them active even during sleep (never really tried it, cause I typically just shut my PC down completely).