# Windows 10 - park drives until manually unparked

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, desktop-computer

Is there any way in Windows 10, either natively or using aftermarket software, to command your hard drives to park and prevent them from unparking until you issue another command?

I've tried using SeaChest to spin one of my drives down or transition it to power state standby_z. But either the transition isn't completing, or Windows is waking it back up again, because every time I check the power mode after, it reports either active or idle_a. Windows Resource Monitor also shows activity on the drive.

<s>Perhaps the most straightforward solution: does sleeping a desktop spin down the drives?</s>

(The purpose of this maneuver is to make the device safe to move on a [computer cart](https://www.newegg.com/p/pl?d=computer+carts) without needing to <s>shut down</s> sleep the computer.)

---

Edit: The "sleep" question has been satisfactorily addressed (the answer is yes). Now I'm curious if there's a way to do it short of sleeping.

---

Spinning down a drive using SeaChest:
[image]

Activity in Resource Monitor after attempted spindown:
[image]

Transitioning to EPC power state standby_z:
[image]

Activity in Resource Monitor after attempted standby_z:
[image]

Comment: Possible dupe of [Does hard disk spin when PC sleeps? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/697238/does-hard-disk-spin-when-pc-sleeps)

Comment: @DavidPostill Good call, thank you. I've mildly amended the question to focus on solutions short of sleeping. That way a) the question breaks new ground on the site, and b) the solutions may be a little more convenient for this use case.

Comment: "Park a drive"?  Now that's a a name I've not heard in a long time.. a long time.  I thought with the death of the MFM drive, so to would be that term.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I'm too young to know what an MFM drive is, but my understanding is that even modern HDDs still involve a needle hovering just above a spinning platter, so head slap is still relevant. Granted, modern drives have accelerometers that will park the heads automatically very quickly if the drive is in free-fall, but I'd still rather play it safe.

Comment: I wasn't picking on you @LastStar007 .. the term made me chuckle.  This is still a good question.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas No offense taken :)

Comment: Swap the hard drive to an SSD. Then you can even use the computer while it is on the cart.

Comment: Set the drive to sleep after 1 minute?  TBH If Windows 'needs' the drive, is there anything you can do about it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does hard disk spin when PC sleeps?](https://superuser.com/questions/697238/does-hard-disk-spin-when-pc-sleeps)

Comment: What is bztransmit64.exe? Looks some backup app. What if you disable it? Could be a candidate for waking up drive, causing defender to acces drive, etc.. You need to use resource monitor to see what initiates access to a drive.

Comment: @user253751 A 4TB SSD is technically a solution, but those are quite expensive.

Comment: @LastStar007 you need 4TB of stuff? maybe see if the big data can be put on a network server instead of on the computer cart

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: Windows is unable to do this due to a decades-old design choice.

Long answer: The Windows kernel uses a disk-backed memory model for commit. This implies that even if no process touches any file on a disk, memory allocations will very likely lead to disk access. Only in sleep or deeper modes is this guaranteed not to happen.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, Windows backs up its RAM onto the HDDs? Does it even back up the RAM onto non-OS drives?

Comment: You can unmount non-OS drives, if all volumes on a physical drive are unmounted, the parking should stick as expected.

Comment: @LastStar007 not exactly "backs up" but it assumes it can swap data between RAM and HDD whenever it feels like, to optimize how the RAM is used. For example you open Word and then browse the internet for a bit; Word can be removed from RAM to make room for more internet because Windows knows if you click on Word it can load it again.

Comment: I see 3 physical disks, this would only apply to one of them.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen That's correct. C: drive is an SSD with the Windows installation. D: and F: are HDDs for programs, documents, etc. Any way to tell which of these Windows is relying on for its "disk-backed memory model"?

Comment: I meant to comment on suggested "disk-backed memory model". IF it it applies, it does have nothing to do with drives other than c:. I downvoted this answer, but judging by the upvotes I am missing something.